# Viewing PMF as an instance of a PDF

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function

I'm having difficulties in thinking about the probability mass function (PMF) as a special case of the probability density function (PDF).

I understand that PMF's are used in discrete examples, but in the extreme, we could have a continuous distribution with small clusters or neighbourhoods around $\mathbb{Z}$ (to simulate the concentrated mass in a point in the discrete case) of infinite density.

Is the modelling of infinite density correct? Or should it be $0$ instead?
Am I missing anything or doing anything wrong?

If you happen to have suggestions of viewing this problem in other ways, do suggest them.

Comment: Could you describe the actual problem that you are facing? What exactly do you want to model and how? What is the problem?

Comment: @StubbornAtom your link seems to point to a linear algebra question that has nothing to do with this Q

Comment: @JuhoKokkala Dear god! I meant this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3095012/thinking-about-pmf-as-an-instance-of-pdf.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been asked by the OP on math.SE as well (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3095012/15941) where it has been answered already.